# clang try catch fails

Tags: c++, exception, clang

Here is the portion of code I speak about.

```
try {
       std::cerr << "first try" << std::endl;
       po::store(po::parse_config_file(ifs, _configFileOptions, false), vm);

} catch(...) {           
       std::cerr << "second try" << std::endl;            
}
```

Just for the seek of details , I m using boost program_options to parse a configuration file. An exception is raised by boost since I put an option in the file that is unrecognized.

There is a problem with Clang not catching this exception. Basically I only see in the output

```
first try
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::program_options::unknown_option> >: unrecognised option 'TestFrequency'
Abort trap: 6
```

Here is my clang version:

```
c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

EDIT: When there is no exception, the parsing and everything works fine.

Comment: What version of boost do you have? Maybe you have better luck using catch(std::exception&)

Comment: boost 1.55. Everything is compiled with Clang against libC++. and yes i tried catch(std::exception&) before submitting the question but it didn t work.

Comment: this is common when boost and the exe are compiled against different standard libraries (i know you mentioned this, but check again).

Comment: @RichardHodges Thanks. I will double check. but shouldn't it throw errors at link time if it is the case?

Comment: I checked. Everything is compiled against libC++. I compiled another boost with libstdc++ and i had link error : undefined symbols.

Comment: The problem with my issue is that everything works as expected unless there is an exception. I know my error comes from some incompatibility in the compilation but why does the linker accept to link incompatible libraries? As if C++ wasn't already enough complex, we added multiple ABI compilers to have more fun

Comment: Have you tried to replace your call with a hardcoded exception throw (`throw 0;` or something similar)? I had problems with GCC (I know it is not related to clang, but just in case) on exception handling when some optimizations were enabled, so compiling with `-O0` is worth trying.

Comment: make sure You don't have misplaced noexcept

Comment: Have you tried adding the -fcxx-exceptions flag to your command-line?

Comment: For me it don't seem to be a compilation problem but a runtime one related to boost library.
What happen if you try to catch error from boost? : 

catch(po::error& e)
{
    cout << e.what();
}

Comment: Linker don't check exception ABI compatibility. C++ need a lot standardization on internal implementation that affect linking different modules built by different compiler for rtti, exception ABI and mangle( Now its a pain when you need rebuild all library by one compiler.
Hope they will bring some standard with this stuff and not just syntax sugar.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the RTTI (Run Time Type Information) issue that is similar to [this issue with GoogleMaps](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9567) or [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737201/problems-throwing-and-catching-exceptions-on-os-x-with-fno-rtti).

Make sure that Boost and your code are compiled without `fno-rtti` flag.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove the linker flags "-Wl,-no_compact_unwind" (Catalina, Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17))