# Catching/Handling exceptions thrown in AngelScript functions

Tags: c++, exception, angelscript

I'm playing around with AngelScript, and one thing I can't seem to wrap my head around is how to catch exceptions thrown from C++ but called from AngelScript. Here's what I've got so far:

```
// test.as

void main()
{
    print("Calling throwSomething...");

    throwSomething();

    print("Call finished");
}
```

`void print(string)` and `void throwSomething()` are two functions registered to the engine, source below. As per the [AngelScript docs](https://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/doc_cpp_exceptions.html):

> Application functions and class methods registered with the script engine are allowed to throw C++ exceptions. The virtual machine will automatically catch any C++ exception, abort the script execution, and return control to the application.

Here's the example code provided for handling exceptions:

```
asIScriptContext *ctx = engine->CreateContext();
ctx->Prepare(engine->GetModule("test")->GetFunctionByName("func"));
int r = ctx->Execute();
if( r == asEXECUTION_EXCEPTION )
{
  string err = ctx->GetExceptionString();
  if( err == "Caught an exception from the application" )
  {
    // An application function threw an exception while being invoked from the script
    ...
  }
}
```

I pretty much verbatim copied this code into my editor and tried to run it. Unfortunately, even though I wrapped the call to `Execute` in a try-catch block, I still get this output:

```
(AngelScript) Calling throwSomething...
(C++) throwSomething Entered...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Assert(1 == 0) failed, line 68
Abort trap: 6
```

For completeness' sake, here's the code for `throwSomething` and `print`:

```
void throwSomething()
{
    cout << "(C++) throwSomething Entered...\n";
    Assert(1 == 0); // will throw an exception
    cout << "(C++) throwSomething Exiting...\n";
}

void print(string s)
{
    cout << "(AngelScript) " << s << "\n";
}
```

So, I'm feeling a little stuck. I tried registering an exception translation function (see linked doc) in hopes that would help, but I still got the same results. From looking at Xcode's debugger, the exception appears to happen in the main thread-- so I'm unsure why neither my code or the code in the AngelScript library itself catches the exception.

So, I guess my question is: 1) how can I either catch the exception within my program, or 2) If I can't catch it from within the program, how can I otherwise handle it without the program crashing?

I'm running this on a ~2015 MacBook Pro running MacOS 10.14.6 and AngelScript version 2.33.0, if that's relevant.

Comment: Have you already checked below link?
https://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/sdk/docs/manual/doc_call_script_func.html

Comment: There isn't much to it, inside the angelscript c++ code it uses try/catch(...) to catch any exception.  We don't know anything about the compiler you used and the compile options applied, very hard to help you.  Otherwise pretty much the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705639/clang-try-catch-fails).