# Why `std::invalid_argument` is not caught with no-rtti in macOS M1 environment?

Tags: c++, macos, c++14, std, rtti

Today I met a weird behaviour in catching exceptions in C++, could anyone clarify it to me? Code snippe

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>


int main() {
  try {
    std::stod("notanumber");
  } catch (const std::invalid_argument&) {
    std::cerr << "std::invalid_argument" << std::endl;
  } catch (const std::out_of_range&) {
    std::cerr << "std::out_of_range" << std::endl;
  } catch (const std::exception&) {
    std::cerr << "Caught by ancestor" << std::endl;
  } catch (...) {
    auto ptr = std::current_exception();
    auto type = __cxxabiv1::__cxa_current_exception_type();
    std::cerr << type->name() << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "..." << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Writes to output

```
St16invalid_argument
...
```

Environment details

```
C++ 14, disabled RTTI
Clang 13.1.6 arm64-apple-darwin-21.6.0
macOS Monterey 12.6
```

I expect exception to be caught on the very first catch block

Upd. Even simplest catch doesn't work for me on the environment

```
try {
  std::stod("notanumber");
} catch (const std::invalid_argument&) { // not caught
  std::cerr << "std::invalid_argument" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Problem disappears with RTTI turned on, but it's still a question for me

Comment: Without RTTI one cannot downcast with dynamic cast. It's most likely that the exception routines rely on it when catching exceptions.

Comment: Possibly related: https://discourse.llvm.org/t/exception-handling-with-rtti-disabled-on-macos/57479.

Comment: @ALX23z   The type of a thrown exception in C++ is determined at runtime, and all catch handlers (other than, notionally, maybe the `...` catch-all`) are required to discriminate based on type of the exception.   For that reason, I have trouble imagining a scheme in which an implementation could work correctly without RTTI.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737201/problems-throwing-and-catching-exceptions-on-os-x-with-fno-rtti https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638237/polymorphically-catching-an-exception-in-a-fno-rtti-shared-library-on-mac-os-x

Comment: See update, even simplest catch with invalid_argument doesn't work on mac m1, but works well on intel. Looks like a compiler bug

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. The close reason makes no sense at all. This is perfectly reproducible on Mac and there is no typo that causes it.

Comment: With RTTI disabled the compiler is not compiling C++. Check your compiler documentation to see what language features might work in this non-standard environment.